# Accessing Variables in a sub ccb-file cocos2d-x

Tags: cocos2d-x

**How to access the member variables defined in sub-ccb, from a custom layer class for the main "ccb" file (cocos2d-x) ?**

Here is the base scenario for this question,

---

I have a CCB file named "ladybirds_page.ccb" and associate custom loader class as follows (root is a CCLayer)

- ladybirds_pageLayerLoader.h
- ladybirds_pageLayer.h
- ladybirds_pageLayer.cpp

and i have another CCB file named "ladybird.ccb" and associate custom loader class as follows (root is a CCNode)

- ladybirdLoader.h
- ladybird.h
- ladybird.cpp

"ladybirds_page.ccb" file contains several instance of "ladybird.ccb". And they are associated  with relevant member variables (mLadyBird_1,mLadyBird_2,..)

and "ladybird.ccb" it self contains several CCSprites associated with member variable (mDotSprite_1, mDotSprite_2,...)

i want to get the access for these sub-ccb(ladyBird)'s member variable for each instance of it. Like

- mLadyBird_1->mDotSprite_1
- mLadyBird_1->mDotSprite_2

---

Here is the my coding approach for this so far,

Create a method names setNumber(int num) in ladyBird.cpp as follows

```
void ladybird::setNumber(int num)
{
    .......
    .........
    mDotSprite_1->setVisible(false);
    mDotSprite_1->setVisible(false);
    ......

}
```

mDotSprite_1 and mDotSprite_1 were assigned using CCB_MEMBERVARIABLEASSIGNER_GLUE macro

```
CCB_MEMBERVARIABLEASSIGNER_GLUE(this, "mDotSprite_1", CCSprite *, this->mDotSprite_1);
CCB_MEMBERVARIABLEASSIGNER_GLUE(this, "mDotSprite_1", CCSprite *, this->mDotSprite_1);
```

loading ladybirds_page.ccb file with its custom loader class

```
void intro_pageLayer::loadNextPage()
{

    /* Create an autorelease CCNodeLoaderLibrary. */
    CCNodeLoaderLibrary * ccNodeLoaderLibrary = CCNodeLoaderLibrary::newDefaultCCNodeLoaderLibrary();

    ccNodeLoaderLibrary->registerCCNodeLoader("ladybird", ladybirdLoader::loader());
    ccNodeLoaderLibrary->registerCCNodeLoader("ladybirds_pageLayer", ladybirds_pageLayerLoader::loader());


    /* Create an autorelease CCBReader. */
    cocos2d::extension::CCBReader * ccbReader = new cocos2d::extension::CCBReader(ccNodeLoaderLibrary);


    /* Read a ccbi file. */
    CCNode * node = ccbReader->readNodeGraphFromFile("ccb/ladybirds_page.ccbi", this);

    ccbReader->release();

    CCScene * scene = CCScene::create();
    if(node != NULL) {
        scene->addChild(node);
    }

    /* Push the new scene with a fancy transition. */

    CCDirector::sharedDirector()->pushScene(CCTransitionPageTurn::create(0.5f, scene, false));
}
```

assign member variable for instance of ladyBirds in ladybirds_pageLayer.cpp

```
 CCB_MEMBERVARIABLEASSIGNER_GLUE(this, "mLadyBird_1", ladybird *, this->mLadyBird_1);
 CCB_MEMBERVARIABLEASSIGNER_GLUE(this, "mLadyBird_2", ladybird *, this->mLadyBird_2);
```

and finally, try to call a method setNumber() on mLadyBird_1 and mLadyBird_2 as follows

```
mLadyBird_1->setNumber(1);
mLadyBird_2->setNumber(2);
```

---

i got EXC_BAD_ACCESS on

```
mDotSprite_1->setVisible(false);
```

Obviously, my scenario was not implemented in my code. So can anybody please enlighten me about the correct way of doing this ?

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem loading CCSprite through

```
CCB_MEMBERVARIABLEASSIGNER_GLUE
```

macro.

I solved it using

```
CCB_MEMBERVARIABLEASSIGNER_GLUE_WEAK
```

macro.

Hope that helps.

**EDIT**

A better solution is use however

```
CCB_MEMBERVARIABLEASSIGNER_GLUE
```

and initialize to NULL the variable

```
variableName = NULL;
```

and gently release into destructor

```
CC_SAFE_RELEASE(variableName);
```

Comment: Wow! It has been more than 3 years. I haven't noticed somebody has answered this old question. Anyway, don't wanna let your effort go not appreciated. So here you go...